# Interfacing VBA / OVH ODBC Connector

Tags: mysql, vba, ovh

I have a **scraping** script with VBA.
I have interfaced this script with a local MySQL database.
Everything works fine.
However, when I want to connect my script to a database on OVH with ODBC Connector, I get the following errors:

- on VBA: Unknown MySql server host
- on ovh: Got an error reading communication packets

How can I unblock this situation

Comment: What kind of OVH database are you using ? a Cloud database (with a public IP), or a Private SQL (with a private IP) ?
If your VBA script is located on your workstation, you need to use an OVH Cloud database with the provided public IP.

Comment: Yes, I use Cloud database, with a public IP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an OVH Cloud Database, check this:

- Ensure you are using the database hostname which looks like `xx12345-00X.dbaas.ovh.net` (and **not** the one which looks like `clouddb0XX.sql00Y`)
- Ensure this hostname is reachable from where your VBA script is running (I assume it's running on your workstation)
- Ensure your IP is allowed on the OVH Cloud Database side: in the OVH Manager > Web Cloud > Database > your database > Authorised IPs: ensure the IP from which your VBA script is reaching this database is allowed.
  You can get this IP with online tools (type "what is my IP" in your favorite search engine) or a simple `curl ifconfig.ovh`
- Ensure your ODBC connector version is compatible with the MySQL version of the OVH Cloud Database